# Plotly Grouped bar chart: hover info of single element

Tags: javascript, plotly, bar-chart

[image]I have copied the grouped bar chart from https://plotly.com/javascript/bar-charts/

```
var trace1 = {
  x: ['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'],
  y: [20, 14, 23],
  name: 'SF Zoo',
  type: 'bar'
};

var trace2 = {
  x: ['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'],
  y: [12, 18, 29],
  name: 'LA Zoo',
  type: 'bar'
};

var data = [trace1, trace2];
var layout = {barmode: 'group'};
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

When I hover over an element, the hover info of both elements shows. How can I show the information of the hovered element only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add hovermode closest {barmode: 'group', hovermode: 'closest'}.